# Creating an array from object properties with Object.keys() vs Object.values()

Tags: javascript, string, function, object, ecmascript-6

Here's an object of cat breeds, and the number of cats in each:

```
const cats = {
  abyssinian: {
    number: 23
  },
  persian: {
    number: 12
  },
  siamese: {
    number: 7
  }
};
```

Suppose I wanted to calculate the total sum of cats. I'll use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to calculate the sum of array values.

But to create an array from the object above, I have two options:

1. [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
2. [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
// object
const cats = { abyssinian: { number: 23 }, persian: { number: 12 }, siamese: { number: 7 } };

// sum array values with reduce
const total = numbers => numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);

// 1.
// create array with Object.keys()
const numbersByKeys = Object.keys(cats).map(breed => cats[breed].number);
console.log(`Sum with Object.keys(): ${total(numbersByKeys)}`);

// 2.
// create array with Object.values()
const numbersByValues = Object.values(cats).map(breed => breed.number);
console.log(`Sum with Object.values(): ${total(numbersByValues)}`);
```

When would I choose one over the other? What are the best practices here?

Comment: There is also Object.enteries where you get [key, value]

Comment: Did you end up doing your own profiling?

Comment: Wow this is old :P Back then jsperf was up, and [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974965/creating-an-array-from-object-properties-with-object-keys-vs-object-values?noredirect=1#comment96714607_54974985) mentioned that `.keys` tended to be faster. But I remember noticing that it also depended on the browser (but that seems strange? I don't know TBH), so I'd just honestly pick what feels more natural. In my example I don't need the keys at all (just the number of cats in each) so I'd pick `.values`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.keys()` if you need to do something with the keys *other* than to retrieve the values. Otherwise, you're only getting the keys in order to access the values, which is redundant if you can get the values directly using a different method - so, in that case, might as well use `Object.values()` from the beginning.

An example of where `Object.keys` could be useful:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2'
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [key, obj[key]]);
console.log(result);
```

You may also use `Object.entries` to get both the key and value at once:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2'
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => key + '---' + val);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! Do you know if there's a difference in terms of performance?

Comment: `Object.keys` is slightly faster when dealing with huge arrays https://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in-with-closure/111 but code clarity and readability is far more important 99% of the time.

Comment: Thank you! I'm dealing with large objects so it could make a difference (believe it or not, the cats breeds object wasn't real).

Comment: Note that I ran the tests on Firefox and`Object.values` is 2x faster than `Object.keys`. It seems that the trend on Chrome is the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

`Array.from(arrayLike [, mapFn [, thisArg]])` is also another method to create an array from an array-like or iterable object and is really simple. Second argument is a map function to call on every element of the array

```js
 const cats = {
    abyssinian: {
      number: 23
    },
    persian: {
      number: 12
    },
    siamese: {
      number: 7
    }
};
const catsArray = Array.from(Object.values(cats), breed => breed.number)
console.log(catsArray);
```

Comment: -1 If they had a separate operation to convert something to an array, followed by `map()`, it would make sense to combine them using `Array.from()`. But in this case, they already have an actual array. So what is the point of `Array.from()`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not actually using the keys, you can use `reduce` with `Object.values` and destructuring to make it simpler and more concise:

```js
const cats = {
  abyssinian: {
    number: 23
  },
  persian: {
    number: 12
  },
  siamese: {
    number: 7
  }
};

const totalCats = Object.values(cats).reduce((acc, { number }) => acc + number, 0);

console.log(totalCats);
```

Comment: What advantage does this have: `((acc, { number })` vs. `((acc, number)`?

Comment: Because it's more concise than `(acc, curr) => acc + curr.number`

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a factor, you may want to stick with `Object.keys`

Here is another person's comparison on the performance of the different ways to iterate over an object.

[“5 Techniques to Iterate Over JavaScript Object Entries and their Performance”](https://link.medium.com/dmY9UeNbMU)

Comment: Thanks for the article! I wonder if the results would be different on Firefox, for example (cf. [this other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974965/creating-an-array-from-object-properties-with-object-keys-vs-object-values/54974985?noredirect=1#comment96715386_54974985))

Answer (score 0):

const object1 = {
"11-15" : 115,
"16-20" : 68,
"21-25" : 4,
"26-30" : 0
};

const result = Object.keys(object1).map((key) => {return {name:key, population:object1[key]}});

//[{ name: "11-15", population: 115 }, { name: "16-20", population: 68 }, { name: "21-25", population: 4 }, { name: "26-30", population: 0 }]

console.log(result);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
var total = Object
  .entries(cats)
  .reduce((acc, [name, {number}])=> acc + number , 0);
console.log(total); // 42
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const iterableValues = function* (obj) { for (let i of Object.values(obj)) yield i;}
let result = 0;
for (let {number} of iterableValues(cats)) result += number;
```